# Firebase multicast cloud messging

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to implement the server side implementation of firebase cloud messaging. This is the body content for sending message based on topic.

```
{
"to" : "/topics/topic_name",
  "priority" : "high",
  "data" : {
    "message" : "Actual message for notification",
    "title" : "Title"
  }
}
```

What i want to know is how to send the above message for a group of reg ids. To field is a string not an array of string. ie., i can send message to reg ids one by one. With GCM we can send the messages to group of ids.

Also what is the limit for sending multicast messages. (1000 reg ids per message).

Kindly let me know if i am missing something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes with Firebase we can send messages to multiple registration ids.
 The syntax is

```
{
"registration_ids":["red_id1","reg_id2",...],
"to" : "/topics/topic_name",
  "priority" : "high",
  "data" : {
    "message" : "Actual message for notification",
    "title" : "Title"
  }
}
```

Regarding limits I think there is no limit in Firebase Notification Service for multicast messaging

Comment: Can you point me to the docs for this. Because i have poured over all the firebase docs. May be i missed it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Got it. Silly me.

Comment: the syntax above has a specific topic that it is targeting, does that mean the registration ids must belong to a particular topic for them to be blasted out?

If I have an array list of tokens, and I wanted to send them push notifications, can I just ignore the topics specifications, since they might be dynamic and cannot be put into a particular topic and subscribe each and every time?

Or if I wanted to do this, would it be safer for me to send one message at a time through the API by looping the list of registration tokens and firing them individually?

Answer (score 0):

i have a doubt with that rinik says 
" I think there is no limit in Firebase Notification Service for multicast messaging"

but if you send a notification or data payload to 1000 registered ids or more you have a limit of 4 kb per request.

Comment: Is it an answer to the question? Why do you post this text as an answer?