# How can I send my push notification with postman to specific users?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I tried this but I can not.. I have this tokens which is upload my app.

```
{
  "to": [
"elQiBKqvtE9wmwfIUCPMaKo:APA91bEdHtb5OD7myU8s6qXoBvnc28SLShhSVTOhCC8h1mEwBq0beMU",

"f3jvheZfQ6GssqcJI__izeB:APA91bHzjLqN17po5K8otCVq5DbOAlujtkkuOEphDenHDou7kNkcxte"

],
  "notification": { 
    "body": "This is push notification",
    "title": "Hello",
    "priority": "high"
  },
  "data": {

    "content_available": true,
    "registration_ids": "null",
    "priority": "high"
  }
}
```

When I try for one token, it success..

```
{
  "to": "elQiBKqvftE9wmwIUCPMaKo:APA91bEdHtD8alnlhakWLTs9RNLgmyx3vPLIVMpyPyJfq0beMU",
  "notification": { 
    "body": "En iyi ürünler mağazamızda sizi bekliyor",
    "title": "Merhaba",
    "priority": "high"
  },
  "data": {
    "slug":"naber",
    "body": "İçerikler burada",
    "title": "Tüm içeriklere ulaşabilirsiniz",
    "content_available": true,
    "registration_ids": "null",
    "priority": "high"
  }
}
```

I want to know how can I send push notifications three or four person at the same time?

Comment: Does this answers your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37840089/firebase-multicast-cloud-messging

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is;

```
{
  "registration_ids":[
"f3jvheZfQ6GsqcJI__izeB:APA91bHzjL_YcePFQ2Ivlq2iVQJ0Ye9iCr7kNkcxe",
"elQiBKqvtE9wmwIUCPMaKo:APA91bEdHtD8alnlhakWLTs9RNLgm8h1mEwBq0beMU"

],

  "notification": { 
    "body": "En iyi ürünler mağazamızda sizi bekliyor",
    "title": "Hello",
    "priority": "high"
  },
  "data": {
    "slug":"naber",
    "body": "İçerikler burada",
    "title": "Tüm içeriklere ulaşabilirsiniz",
    "content_available": true,
    "registration_ids": "null",
    "priority": "high"
  }
}
```